# How Can I return the Dynamic List From DataTable to View From Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, datatable

I have a stored Procedure `stp_GetContractBillingDetailReportEquinoxByResultGrouping_Vivek` which gives dynamic Data. The Column of the data may be different According to Start Date and End Date Parameter. For Ex:- IF start Date Parameter is `1/1/2018` and End Date Parameter is `31/1/2018` the Result Provides Only One Column January 2018. Similarly, IF start Date Parameter is `1/1/2018` and End Date Parameter is `31/12/2019` the Result Provides 24 Col from January 2018 to December 2019. Now I have created DataTable which must return all the list in order to show in View. How Can I return this List to View From Controller?

My Controller Code is:

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetContractBillingList([FromBody] ContractBillingExportToExcelSearchViewModel model)
        {
             var contractBillingList =  
   ReportService.DatatableContractBilling(model);
            return Ok(contractBillingList);
        }
```

and My c# Service Code is :

```
public DataTable DatatableContractBilling(ContractBillingExportToExcelSearchViewModel model)
        {



            StringBuilder strSQL = new StringBuilder();


                strSQL.AppendFormat(@"stp_GetContractBillingDetailReportEquinoxByResultGrouping_Vivek");


            SqlParameter[] _parameters = new SqlParameter[2];
            _parameters[0] = new SqlParameter("@PeriodStart", model.FromDate);
            _parameters[1] = new SqlParameter("@PeriodEnd", model.ToDate);


            DataTable dt = _dapperRepository.ExecuteDataTableProc(strSQL.ToString(), _parameters);
            return dt;

        }
```

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ee01e6/different-way-to-convert-datatable-to-list/

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the `DataTable` like

```
<table>
    <tr>
        @foreach (System.Data.DataColumn column in Model.Columns)
        {
            <th>
                @column.ColumnName
            </th>
        }
    </tr>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in Model.Rows)
        {
            <th>
                @foreach (var cell in row.ItemArray)
                {
                    @cell.ToString();
                }
            </th>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```